# Criar Menu Infinito PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, menu

Estou tentado criar um menu infinito, já montei o objeto da forma que preciso, mas não consigo imprimir. Deve ser algo parecido com isso:

```
User
User > User1
User > User2
User > User2 > User3
User > User2 > User4
User > User3
User > User3 > User5
.....
```

Meu Objeto:

```
[
(int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

    'id' => (int) 1,
    'nome' => 'Administrador',
    'parent_id' => null,
    'children' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

            'id' => (int) 2,
            'nome' => 'Revenda Teste 1',
            'parent_id' => (int) 1,
            'children' => []
        },
        (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

            'id' => (int) 3,
            'nome' => 'Revenda Teste 2',
            'parent_id' => (int) 1,
            'children' => []
        },
        (int) 2 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

            'id' => (int) 6,
            'nome' => 'Revenda Teste 3',
            'parent_id' => (int) 1,
            'children' => [],

        },
        (int) 3 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

            'id' => (int) 7,
            'nome' => 'Revenda Teste 4',
            'parent_id' => (int) 1,
            'children' => [
                (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

                    'id' => (int) 8,
                    'nome' => 'Revendedor Teste 5',
                    'parent_id' => (int) 7,
                    'children' => [
                        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

                            'id' => (int) 15,
                            'nome' => 'Revendedor do Rev 5',
                            'parent_id' => (int) 8,
                            'children' => [],

                },
                (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

                    'id' => (int) 9,
                    'nome' => 'Revenda Teste 6',
                    'parent_id' => (int) 7,
                    'children' => [
                        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

                            'id' => (int) 14,
                            'nome' => 'Revenda Teste 7',
                            'parent_id' => (int) 9,
                            'children' => []
                        }
                    ]

                }
            ]

        }
    ]

}
]
```

Meu código:

```
public function menuList($lists) {
    $n = "";
    if(!is_array($lists)){
        $lists = $lists->toArray();
    }
    echo "<br>";
    foreach($lists as $element) {
        echo $n .=  $element->nome . " > ";
        if($element->children){
            $this->menuList($element->children);
        }
    }
 }
```

Minha saída:

```
Administrador >
Revenda Teste 1 > Revenda Teste 1 > Revenda Teste 2 > Revenda Teste 1 >
Revenda Teste 2 > Revenda Teste 3 > Revenda Teste 1 > Revenda Teste 2 >
Revenda Teste 3 > Revenda Teste 4 > 
Revendedor Teste 5 >
Revendedor do Rev 5 > Revendedor Teste 5 > Revenda Teste 6 >
Revenda Teste 7 >
```

Comment: E como tentou fazer? Sabe o que é recursividade?

Comment: sim, tentei com recursividade, mas não consegui chegar no resultado pretendido, sei que esse é o caminho... mas não sei como chegar.

Comment: Coloque na pergunta a sua tentativa e o resultado que obteve.

Comment: pronto... adicionei o código e a saída.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
public function menuList($lists, $n = "") {
    if(!is_array($lists)){
        $lists = $lists->toArray();
    }
    for($x = 0; $x < count($lists); $x++){
        $element = $lists[$x];
       echo $n.$element->nome . "<br>";
        if($element->children){
            $n .= $element->nome . " > ";
            $this->menuList($element->children, $n);
            $count = strlen($element->nome . " > ");
            $n = substr($n, 0, -$count);
        } 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Só uma observaçao. Acabei o usando o for porque estava fazendo de outra forma. Mas da para usar o foreach também.

Comment: A saída não ficou como esperado, além de repetir os valores, ficou inline, em havia chegado em algo parecido, mas o seu foi mais próximo, acredito que falta algum detalhe simples....

Comment: @LaercioNunes desculpa... Fiz uma edição. Quando eu fui moldar para o seu código esqueci de alterar uma parte. Da uma olhada agora.

Comment: perfeito é a palavra... fico exatamente como eu preciso. Muito obrigado!!!!

Comment: @LaercioNunes tranquilo. Não esquece de avaliar a resposta. =) Abraço!

Comment: Eu Avaliei, mas como minha reputação ainda é baixa, apareceu a seguinte mensagem:

Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: Foi! Valeu, man!